# excel reference column A in sheet2 from column A in sheet1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a columnA in **sheet1** like:

[image]

I wanna create a column in sheet2 that exactly reference to this column in sheet1. But:

1. when I insert number "10" in ColumnA sheet1, ColumnA in Sheet2 shall automatically add this "10" as well.
2. when I delete number "5" in ColumnA sheet1, ColumnA in Sheet2 shall automatically delete this "5" as well.

[image]

So basically I want the range of column to be reference/dynamic. If we use {vlookup} or simple reference "='Sheet1!A5", that will give #REF! or #N/A, but the error line is still there.

Does anyone know whether this is achievable in excel?

Comment: what version of excel do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW())&""="","",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW()))
```

Copy this down as far as you think will cover the most that will ever be on sheet1

If one has Office 365 then simply put:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A<>"")
```

in the first cell and it will spill the results and change as the range changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula [`Indirect()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) to pull this off.

`Indirect()` allows you to refer to a cell by its name, instead of referring to it directly. This way even if you delete a row, the name itself still exists so `Indirect()` is happy.

In `Sheet2`, cell `A1`:

```
=Indirect("Sheet1!A" & Row())
```

Copy and paste down and it should behave the way you are asking.

I'm using `Row()` as well so you can copy/paste this formula instead of having to hard code the row number in the cell name. You could just as well do `=Indirect("Sheet1!A1")` but then you can't copy the formula down without changing the formula manually in every row, and who has time for that?

You noted in the comment that you get back `0` when the cell referrenced in indirect is empty. In that case just wrap this formula an in `if()` to suppress `0` values:

```
=If(Indirect("Sheet1!A" & Row()) = 0, "", Indirect("Sheet1!A" & Row()))
```

Comment: This almost works! but the only issue is - If i delete "5" in sheet1, then sheet1 will have 8 rows (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9), while sheet2 is still having 9 rows (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0). The last row of sheet2 becomes 0, which means that, whenever i delete 1 row in sheet1, sheet2 will replace 0 from the last row.

Comment: Just updated the question with a workaround for that. Short of introducing some really ugly VBA, it's going to be necessary that every cell in Column "A" (for at least as many rows that you want to watch for in Sheet1) will need to contain this formula.

Comment: The 0 trick plays more like "not showing anything", but if I have a column B in sheet2 that relies on Column A Sheet 2 to do the calculation (say =A1+1), then "" + 1 will give #VALUE! for the last rows in sheet2 if I delete some rows in sheet1....

Comment: will there be a way to align the length of both sheets? overall this is already a very good method! thx

Comment: I think you'll have to account for a blank in your `sheet2` `B` column formula with `IF(A1="", "", A1+1)` or similar. There is also an option at the workbook level to show `0` valued cells as empty, which may be fitting for your usecase. Then you can just leave your formulas simple with out the `IF()` wrapper. Ultimately you are threading the needle between the correct logic for your needs `=Indirect()` and presentation to the end user (The `If()` wrapper). I would worry more about the logic and then mess with the presentation at the end as you may find some more elegant way to deal with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but too large to fit into a comment)

I advise you to check the `Worksheet_Change` event for that, that macro might be launched whenever something is changed to a sheet, but beware:

Imagine you have following situation:

Sheet A:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sheet B:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

You say that removing `3` in sheet A also should cause removing `3` in sheet B and vice versa, but what when you have two columns:

Sheet 1:

```
1    Brussels
2    Ghent
3    Kortrijk
4    Brugge
5    Wervik
```

and sheet 2:

```
1    Berlin
2    Köln
3    Frankfurt
4    Stuttgart
5    Reichenbach
```

Which of the four possibilities should it become?

### Possibility 1: (remove cell in sheet 1 and cell in sheet 2)

Sheet 1

```
1    Brussels
2    Ghent
4    Kortrijk
5    Brugge
     Wervik
```

Sheet 2:

```
1    Berlin
2    Köln
4    Frankfurt
5    Stuttgart
     Reichenbach
```

### Possibility 2: remove entire row in sheet 1 and single cell in sheet 2

Sheet 1

```
1    Brussels
2    Ghent
4    Brugge
5    Wervik
```

Sheet 2:

```
1    Berlin
2    Köln
4    Frankfurt
5    Stuttgart
     Reichenbach
```

### Possibility 3: remove single cell in sheet 1 and entire row in sheet 2)

Sheet 1

```
1    Brussels
2    Ghent
4    Kortrijk
5    Brugge
     Wervik
```

Sheet 2:

```
1    Berlin
2    Köln
4    Stuttgart
5    Reichenbach
```

### Possibility 4: remove entire row in sheet 1 and entire row in sheet 2)

Sheet 1

```
1    Brussels
2    Ghent
4    Brugge
5    Wervik
```

Sheet 2:

```
1    Berlin
2    Köln
4    Stuttgart
5    Reichenbach
```