# How can I get the values from one column that match a given arguement and put them in another column without leaving blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is probably a simple task for most but given the following example how could I pull out the rows that have a value of greater than 0 and put them in another column without the cells that contain 0 leaving a blank row?

```
1
0
7
1
0
4
0
0
```

But I would like to achieve

```
1
7
1
4
```

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: Check this **[Already Provided Solution By Scott Craner Sir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71768742/8162520)** instead of `<>""` use `>0`

Comment: Within same workbook or other workbook also its working just found out and tried, could you please let us know further

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya I've managed to get the filter version Scott Craner provided but the version of office I'll be needed this for won't have the filter function, I've tried using =IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW())&""="","",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW())) but am having trouble getting it working. For reference this is what I ended up using for the filter function =FILTER(Sheet2!E2:E18,Sheet2!E2:E18<>0)

Comment: For those excel versions you may try using the `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` Function

Comment: @Mark727 it will be like this assuming from the post you dont have a header, `=INDEX('Blad1'!$D$1:$D$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Blad1'!$D$1:$D$8))/('Blad1'!$D$1:$D$8>0),ROW(A1)))` and if there is a header then `=INDEX('Blad1'!$D$2:$D$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Blad1'!$D$2:$D$9)-ROW('Blad1'!$D$2)+1)/('Blad1'!$D$2:$D$9>0),ROW(A1)))` using `>0` is better it excludes the `-ve` values as well but if you need them then use `<>0`